# Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined" in mounted hook (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

ScrollIntoView returns undefined

I am trying to scroll into the element when navigate to that page:

```
scrollTo(itemId) {
  this.$refs['item' + itemId].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'nearest',
  })
},
```

The point is that it's getting called inside the mounted hook. ref is defined itemId is also defined which is a query parameter from vue router but it still throws
**error in a mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined"**

What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Comment: How do you call `scrollTo` and how do reference the elements?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I set inside the div:
:ref="'item' + item.itemId"

It's inside the loop getting generated. And in mounted hook when I call scrollTo  I set argument this.$route.query.itemId

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it looks the reason is this:
this.$refs['item' + itemId] which returns undefined but when I console.log this.$refs it returns object with  item889  which exists. 889 is also passing to the method as itemId so why it throws undefined?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that dynamic refs are not ready in mounted hook, so try to watch the `$route` object and scroll to the desired element :

```
watch:{
$route:{
    handler(to,from){

         if(to.query.itemId){
           this.scrollTo(to.query.itemId)
         },
    deep:true //because $route is an object
   }
}

}
```

But I think that you should use something like [scroll-behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior)

Comment: Seems it's not getting called inside watch

Comment: anyway doesn't gett called

Comment: try to log the `to` and `from` before `if(...)`

Comment: I think issue is not the implementation way but more how can be specifiv ref be accesses ed. this.$refs['item' + itemId] looks like wrong

Comment: please share the v-for loop

Comment: Because $refs returns an object in the console containing properties that have the above generated ref name

Comment: I've added an image how this.$refs look like in the console. So I need somehow access specific ref from this list that has the right propertyname

Comment: And that's what item  + query.itemId

Comment: Try out `if(this.$refs['item' + itemId]){this.$refs['item' + itemId][0].scrollIntoView({`

Comment: Nope. If the ref was just an "item" you could access it with this.$refs.item but here we have combied with id

Comment: could you create a codesandbox example in order to debug it?